# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf'

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, permission-denied

I have problem with:

```
for line in open("/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf", mode="r", encoding="utf8"):
    print(line)
```

Result is:

> IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf'

What is problem?

Comment: I suspect you lack read permissions on the file.

Comment: You probably can't view the file contents from the command line either? Try ``cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`` from your shell, running as the same user as your python script.

Comment: You could try running it as administrator, that might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
sudo python [yourcode]
```

or

```
chmod 777 /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
python [yourcode]
```